# SQL Place data into pairs where times/schedules do not overlap

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm not sure if this is possible with sql..thought I'd consult the masses.

I'm looking to take table data in the format below.

```
employee   start         stop
bob        9:00          17:00
steve      17:30         0:30
rick       9:30          17:30
```

and pair as many records as possible where the schedule does not overlap (with a 30 minute buffer).

result:

```
steve, bob
rick
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like the kind of operation that is easily done in SQL.

Comment: Do you want only pairs even if there are larger groups of non-overlapping rows, e.g. if `a`, `b` and `c` don't overlap then you want `a,b`, `a,c`, `b,c` rather than `a,b,c`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! This would be used to assign seats/work stations to be shared by 2 employees. So the data would be in pairs with no overlap or if no pair exists then it would be a single. Hopefully that makes sense.. so the pairs would be distinct.. once a, b was paired a & b would not be used again.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient, but it will get the job done.

```
create table Emp (Emp Varchar(10), 
                  Start TIME, 
                  Stop TIME,
                  StartDateTime AS CAST('2000-01-01 ' + CAST(Start AS Varchar(5)) AS DateTImE),
                  StopDateTime AS DATEADD(day,CASE WHEN Stop<Start THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                  CAST('2000-01-01 ' + CAST(Stop AS Varchar(5)) AS DateTImE))
)
GO

INSERT INTO EMP VALUES ('bob','09:00','17:00')
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES ('steve','17:30','00:30')
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES ('rick','09:00','17:30')
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES ('james','07:00','09:00')

select * from 
EMP AS Emp1
LEFT JOIN EMP AS Emp2 ON 
DATEADD(minute,30,Emp1.StopDateTime) <= Emp2.StartDateTime OR Emp1.StartDateTime >= DATEADD(minute,30,Emp2.StopDateTime)
WHERE Emp1.Emp > Emp2.Emp OR Emp2.Emp IS NULL
```

You can also make the computed columns persistant and index them for better performance.

Comment: Where does your code handle the 30 minute buffer in the question?

Comment: Thanks! This is almost perfect.. I forgot to mention I'm using Oracle PL/SQL so I changed it slightly to account for the lack of dateadd.

The query provides every possible match... can you think of a way to only show 1 match per employee?

Comment: I think I need to check somehow if emp2 has been matched already

Comment: What you're talking about is distributing the Emps into pods of 2's. This can't be solved by a simple SQL because as you progess with the assignments, the data will change.  For instance in this case you have Steve that will be matched with both BoB and James. But eventually will be coupled with only one of them.  The way as I see it is to sort the matches for instance by whith how many other people each emp could be matched. Then start removing couples from the least amount available to the most dynamic ones.  Each time removing all the pairs of the ones you chose.